# How to insert key while traversing from root to the destination node of a json tree?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, vue.js, tree

lets say my JSON tree will have structure like below

```
 var tree = [{
        iriID: "/api/catalogs/7",
        id: 7,
        name: "drywall",

        children: [{
                iriID: "/api/catalogs/11",
                id: 11,
                name: "Vipuls catalog",

                children: [{
                        iriID: "/api/catalogs/10",
                        id: 10,
                        name: "test catalog 3",

                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        iriID: "/api/catalogs/9",
                        id: 9,
                        name: "test catalog",

                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            },

        ]
    },


];
```

I want to insert a key travelled=true while traversing from the first node to the node which has id=9 . The final output should look like the one below.

```
      var tree = [{
        iriID: "/api/catalogs/7",
        id: 7,
        name: "drywall",
        traversed: true,
        children: [{
                iriID: "/api/catalogs/11",
                id: 11,
                name: "Vipuls catalog",
                traversed: true,
                children: [{
                        iriID: "/api/catalogs/10",
                        id: 10,
                        name: "test catalog 3",

                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        iriID: "/api/catalogs/9",
                        id: 9,
                        name: "test catalog",
                        traversed: true,
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            },

        ]
    },


];
```

I hope you have understood my requirement. Just see to it that the code for finding the shortest path is optimized and well functional.

Comment: `child.traversed = true`? Or for Vue to pick up changes, `this.$set(child, 'traversed', true)`. Where is your code where you traverse the tree?

Comment: Do you really need/want to modify your tree? Would be wiser to keep your traversal info in a separate structure imo.

Comment: yeah whichever way you find please share, modifying also may be fine

Comment: It is strange that your tree is an array? As a tree has just one root, what would it mean if this array had two or more elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a recursive function to collect the nodes that are on the path to the target node. Then you can decide to do what you want with the nodes on that path, e.g. give them that extra property:

```js
function getPathTo(nodes, id) {
    for (let node of nodes) {
        if (node.id === id) return [node];
        let path = getPathTo(node.children || [], id);
        if (path) return [node, ...path];
    }
}

// Demo
var tree = [{iriID: "/api/catalogs/7",id: 7,name: "drywall",children: [{iriID: "/api/catalogs/11",id: 11,name: "Vipuls catalog",children: [{iriID: "/api/catalogs/10",id: 10,name: "test catalog 3",children: []}, {iriID: "/api/catalogs/9",id: 9,name: "test catalog",children: []}]}]}];
let path = getPathTo(tree, 9) || [];
console.log(path.map(node => node.id));
path.forEach(node => node.traversed = true);
console.log(tree);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by recursive traversing.

```
function modify(ob, id) {
    if(ob.id == id) {
        ob[traversed] = true
    } else {
        for(var i=0;i<ob.children.length;i++){
            modify(ob.children[i],id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your attempt is useful but doesn't produce the above result.